# Class Variable that have get and set access inside class but outside class only get access in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Eg:-
In Player Class, Score should have get and set access inside Class but outside class score should only be read-only property.

```
Class Player{
   var score : Int  //get and set
   init(score : Int){ 
       self.score = score
   }
   func printScore(){
      print(score)
   }
   func updateScore(by value: Int){
       self.score += value
   }
}
let player1 = Player(score : 30)
print(player1.score) //=> should be allowed
player.score = 100  //=> should not be allowed
```

Comment: Make it private renaming it for instance `private var _score`? And use another one only for the get for extern use: `var score { return _score }` (here, `get` is implicit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is handled by the `private(set)` access control:

```
private(set) var score : Int
```

See [Getters and Setters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID17) in The Swift Programming Language for full details on these access controls.